# Shape changes other shapes | Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

So i got my "Player" shape (Just a Picture box) and my "Ball" (Ovalshape from powerpacks) 
[image: A Ball and a Panel]

and when they collide the Ball(Ovalshape) starts changing the "Player" (The Picturebox) like this:
[image: A Ball and a broken Panel]

so what do ya think? How Can i fix this? 
Thanks for some future answers!

Answer (score 0):

So i found an Answer myself, here it is:

The Name of my Picturebox "Player" is "P1"

Now you create a new **Timer** that you call "Update" and set the interval to 1.

Now you make a new Sub: Form1 load

in this Sub you write:

```
Update.Enabled = True
```

And in our Timer "Update" you write:

```
P1.Visible = false
P1.visible = True
```

*WARNING: **FIRST FALSE** THEN TRUE*

Its not an Perfect solution but it works as intendet.